# Number of parameters in the SQL stored procedure Groovy

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, groovy, parameters, call

In my groovy code I have to call a SQL stored procedure with a large number of parameters (**70**).

```
new Sql(dataSource_myDataSource).call("{call Sp_StoredProcedure(?, ?, ?, ?, ...) }",
            [
                cmd.blankid,  
                session?.user.sdk,
                cmd.one,
                cmd.two,
                //and so on

            ])
```

**Question:** Is there any way to avoid filling the Sp_StoredProcedure( ) with 70 question marks?

-- Thanks, Qubit

Comment: How are arguments constructed? What comes after cmd.two? cmd.three? ... cmd.seventy?

Comment: One, two, three and the others are of String or Date type. They come simply one after another: cmd.one, cmd.two, ..., cmd.N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always construct the query:

```
sql_query = "<prefix>"
sql_query += "?, " * 69
sql_query += "?)<suffix>"
```

Comment: Thank you Mishik, I'll try that way.